# change parameterization to eliminate weight constraints in neural networks

Tags: neural-network, optimization

I am wondering if it makes sense to use a parameterization to eliminate simple weight inequalities, for example if the weights should be $w\geq 0$, one cound train $\exp w$ over the unconstrained set instead. Also, if $\sum w_i=1$ one could parameterize $\frac{e^{w_i}}{\sum e^{w_i}}$ and optimize over the unconstrained set.

While the solutions should be similar to e.g. using a corresponding constraint in tensorflow, I wonder if it makes numerically a difference, and what way is the right one. I guess the values of $\exp$ might explode and it becomes numerically instable.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

For other people asking this question: In keras / tensorflow I observed way better results using custom constraints instead of a parameterization. When using a parameterization, the weights stayed more or less the same (the initial value), probably another step size is needed compared to linear weights, while on the other hand, using a custom constraint, the constrained weights keep their linearity, so the same step size can be used as for the other linear weights intuitively.